# Creating a web client in Dart

Tags: google-chrome-extension, dart, httprequest

I'm starting with Dart, and I want to create an app to make http request to a web page
and maybe transform it to a chrome extension, all this with Dart.

The problem that i have it's that i don't know how to send a HttpRequest to this
page "http://www.1001tracklists.com/" to retrieve the html content and then organize 
all the sessions in my app with html and css.

All what I have tried is to make a normal HttpRequest, but I receive an error due to a CORS request, and I don't have any idea how to solve the problems with the headers.

Answer (score 1):

The server would be required to make modifications to incorporate CORS headers to allow remote requests to query resources from their server.

Most (all?) modern browsers automatically incorporate CORS and so any requests from them will automatically create an `Origin:` header in the request. If the receiving server does not have an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:` header which will match your Origin, the request will fail.

An alternative may be to have a script on your server query the data and you poll your own server to fetch the data. See the [CORS Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) for more details.

Comment: Although true in the general case, the question's being `Google Chrome Extension`-related changes things drastically (take a look at **[Zig Mandel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20761053/creating-a-web-client-in-dart#answer-20763110)**).

Answer (score 1):

With chrome extensions you can bypass cors by simply stating the urls you need to access in your manifest. Look it up in chrome extensions. See: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add CORS headers as above if you have control of your server side, or setup apache/nginx to do this for you as reverse proxies, or you need access to a CORS proxy server.

Have look [here](http://oscf.org.uk/proxy-server.html) to see if this can help you.